# Is every point of every open set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ a limit point of E? Answer the same question for closed sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

I have found a solution for this problem but I do not understand it.

Take a point $x$ in $E$. Since $E$ is open, $x$ is an interior point of $E$. Since $x$ is an interior point in $E$, then $\exists$ an open ball of radius $\alpha$ such that $B_{\alpha}(x) \subset E$.

We are examining $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a metric space. A natural metric is the norm for $\mathbb{R}^2$. The ball of radius $\alpha$ around $x$ also contains a point $y$ which is an element of both the ball and $E$. So $d(x,y) < \alpha$.

We want to show that for any arbitrary $r>0$ an open ball around $x$ intersect $E - {x}$ is nonempty.

Is there some way we can formally show this?

Answer (score 0):

It's true that if $E$ is a nonempty open set in $\mathbb R^n$, then every point of $E$ is a limit point of $E$ (the claim is vacuously true for $\varnothing$). Let $x\in E$ and choose $x_n\in E$ such that $0<d(x,x_n)<\frac1n$. Then $x_n$ is a sequence in $E\setminus\{x\}$ that converges to $x$, so $x$ is a limit point of $E$.

It's not true for closed sets though - just take $\{x\}$ for example.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without sequences?